# What is this extra character python puts before every field in an sql query?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
>>> c.execute('select * from zeol').fetchall()
[(u'BBUL1', u'BCF-0106', u'', u'ENVIR', u'2011-01-25', u'18:02:10.92', 
  u'***', u'ALARM', u'', u'', u'33387', u'7401', u'EXTERNAL AL 1', 
  u'SYSTEM ON BATTERY', u''), (u'BBUL1', u'BCF-0106', u'', u'ENVIR', 
  u'2011-01-25', u'18:02:10.92', u'***', u'ALARM', u'', u'', u'33389', 
  u'7401', u'EXTERNAL AL 1', u'SYSTEM ON BATTERY', u''), (u'BBUL1', 
  u'BCF-0106', u'', u'ENVIR', u'2011-01-25', u'18:02:10.93', u'***', u'ALARM',
  u'', u'', u'33389', u'7401', u'EXTERNAL AL 1', u'SYSTEM ON BATTERY', u'')]
```

all the 'u's are not there in the sqlite database.

Comment: see the Python language reference manual at http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that means that this is python unicode string.

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the Python syntax for string constants; it means each string constant is a sequence of Unicode codepoints rather than 8-bit bytes.  It shows up in the interactive environment because that uses `repr` to dump complex data structures.  It won't show up if you use `print` or `write` on individual strings.

Answer (score 0):

The 'u' prefix indicates the string is unicode. For more information on string encoding/decoding with python, see [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes)